# Assigning values to method using for loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop

Bit of a rookie question. I would like to read values from a single column in a csv, and then parse each value through an await method to pull data from an API and append the data to a json.

This would resemble this pseudo code: 
i.) read csv['id'], ii.) for each value in the column add value to API call, iii.) append to json, iv.) continue until all values in column are completed.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
async function writeData() {
    const csv = require('csv-parser')
    const results = [];
    fs.createReadStream('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\testingclean.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data',(data)=> results.push(data))
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log(results)
        });
    const cookieJar = await getCookieJar();
    const fighter = await boxrec.getPersonById(cookieJar,468841);
```

This currently only reads the csv and pull data for person with ID 468841, I am very new to node.js and can't figure out how to assign the value to getPersonById based on the value in the Id column that I am iterating through.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
{
    '': '49',
    id: '512687',
    name: 'Joey Dawejko',
    age: '29.0',
    last6: "['win', 'win', 'loss', 'loss', 'loss', 'win']",
    points: '34',
    rating: '50',
    stance: 'orthodox',
    draw: '4',
    loss: '7',
    win: '20',
    countryid: 'US',
    countryName: 'USA',
    cityName: 'Philadelphia'
  }
]
{
  '': '0',
  id: '489762',
  name: 'Andy Ruiz Jr',
  hasBoutScheduled: 'True',
  last6: "['win', 'loss', 'win', 'win', 'win', 'win']",
  points: '754',
  rating: '100',
  stance: 'orthodox',
  draw: '0',
  loss: '1',
  win: '33',
  countryid: 'US',
  countryName: 'USA',
  cityName: 'Imperial'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would give a heads up.

```
async function writeData() {
  const csv = require('csv-parser')
  const results = [];
  fs.createReadStream('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\testingclean.csv')
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data',(data)=> results.push(data))
      .on('end', async () => {
        const cookieJar = await getCookieJar();
        const promises = [];
        results.forEach((data) => {
          promises.push(boxrec.getPersonById(cookieJar,data.id));
        })

        const fighters = await Promise.all(promises); // Fighters is an array
        fighters.forEach((fighter) => {
          // DO STUFF USING FIGHTER
        })
      });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, mind explaining what the code after const cookieJar does

Comment: UPDATED! Do things once the reading is done. Iterating over `results` array and fetching `id`. Then, calling the `getPersonById` with the id. `getPersonById` returns a promise, so we are storing that promise inside the array. Then using `Promise.all` to wait until all the promises are resolved. Finally `fighters` contains all the data as an array that `getPersonById` returns. Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks. Seem to be getting the error: const cookieJar = await getCookieJar();
                              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: My bad. Need to add `async` in front of `end` callback. UPDATED!

Comment: works, just to confirm I can just use fs.writeFileSync('name.json', JSON.stringify(fighters.output)); to produce a json with all the output right?

Comment: Yes its possible.

Comment: seems to be returning an error message, but will post as a separate question